# How to cancel axios request?

Tags: react-native, axios

I have `TextInput` and I need to send request every time when the text is changing
I have this code:

```
// Main.js

import Api from 'network/ApiManager';
const api = new Api();

// TextInput onChangeText function

const getSearch = useCallback(
 async (searchName, sectorTypeId, type, filterData) => {
  const result = await api.controller.search(searchName, sectorTypeId, type, filterData);
  console.log(result)
 },
[],
);
```

And i have this network layer

```
// NetworkManager.js

async getData(url) {
try {
  const {data: response} = await axios.get(url);
  return response;
} catch (e) {
  return response;
}
}

controller = {
    profile: async (search, sector, f_type, filterData = {}) => {
      const res = await this.getData('/url/path');
      return this.transformToOptions(res);
    },
  };
```

When `onChangeText` is called, I send a lot of requests, but I want to cancel previous requests and get the latest only. I know that I need to use `CancelToken` but I don't know how to pass it on my network layer
Please help

Comment: You might also want to look at debouncing your input. If a typical user types 4 characters before waiting to see what results come back, you're going to be aborting 75% of the requests you're making here.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cancelToken, whenever a request comes, you can save the cancel token, when a new request comes, cancelToken won't be undefined, thus you can call `cancelToken.cancel()`. Try something like this:

```
let cancelToken    
if (typeof cancelToken != typeof undefined) {
        cancelToken.cancel("Operation canceled due to new request.")
      }
    
      //Save the cancel token for the current request
      cancelToken = axios.CancelToken.source()
    
      try {
        const results = await axios.get(
          `Your URL here`,
          { cancelToken: cancelToken.token } //Pass the cancel token
        )
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it canceled all requests, not duplicate requests